# How to change Wildfly server's IP address

Tags: ip-address, wildfly

I'm working on preparing a program that runs on Wildfly for deployment to a customer site, and I need to change the IP address that Wildfly launches on. How do I configure Wildfly to start up at, for example, 127.0.0.2 instead of 127.0.0.1?

---

#### Update

I'm running Wildfly as a service on Windows.

Answer (score 11):

Either you can bind the address through passing the arguments while starting the server like

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -b=127.0.0.2
```

https://sourcevirtues.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/set-wildfly-binding-address-and-shutdown-from-cli/

or it can be configured in host.xml file

```
<interface name="public">

    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.2}"/>

</interface>
```

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/how-to-access-jboss-as-over-a-network

Update : To run as service, you will need to set some variables in service.bat as well

```
set CONTROLLER=localhost:9990 // here set your ip:9990 and other required details

    set DC_HOST=master
    set IS_DOMAIN=false
    set LOGLEVEL=INFO
    set JBOSSUSER=admin  //management admin user
    set PASSWORD=pwd  //management admin password
```

Comment: Will the second solution work when running Wildfly as a Windows service?

Comment: Worked for me on Wildfly 10.1.0 Final running on Linux. Just in case anyone wants WildFly to listen on port 80, here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32489265/1657502

Answer (score 3):

You could set different ip address by changing public interface in the standalone.xml file. It should look like this:

```
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.2}"/>
</interface>
```

So, the server is now listening only on the specified ip address (after restarting). If you want allow all available network interfaces, you should place 0.0.0.0 instead (be careful with this).