# How can i run wildfly 8 in port 80

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

How can i run wildfly 8.2.1 in port 80? I can run wildfly in different ports by changing the offset as below.

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}">
```

But unable to run in port 80.

Comment: Have you checked if there is something else using the port 80? Try netstat -na in your command line and check if the port is in use

Comment: It may help if you include things such as: - error received when setting the port to 80 (look for jboss.http.port in standalone.xml) - what your current settings look like

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Offset adds that value to all ports. So if you had http set to the default port 8080, an offset of 100 would set it to 8180.

You want to set the socket for http.

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:80}"/>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Alternatively, all of these values can be passed in via command line. so you can run: standalone.sh -Djboss.http.port=80

Note: on some operating systems: OSX and variants of Linux you must be superuser to bind things to port 80.

Comment: Worked for me on Wildfly 10.1.0 Final running on Linux. Just in case anyone wants WildFly to listen on all server addresses, here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31669730/1657502

Comment: As said, for setting up the port to 80, probably you need to change _user_ to _root_ in _/etc/systemd/system/wildfly.service_ if you start it as a service on Linux