# How to change the IP address of Wildfly server

Tags: java, servlets, wildfly

I have a wildfly 10 running on localhost:8085, containing inside a servlet which will return some result data when a client sending request for it. When I test with my web browser on my local computer, it works fine. Now I would like to use an external device, for example RaspberryPi to send request to this servlet. How can I change IP address of the Wildfly server from localhost to maybe the IP address of my computer so that my RaspberryPi can send request to. Thank you

Comment: I think this question is already answered there
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658647/how-to-change-wildfly-servers-ip-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change the IP directly in the wildfly configuration (`standalone.xml` or whatever your config profile is) within

```
<interfaces>
   <interface name="management">
       <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
   </interface>
   <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
   </interface>
    ....
</interfaces>
```

or specify the bind address as startup parameter:

`standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0`

or `standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0`

Note that `0.0.0.0` will force JBoss bind to all network adapters, you can also specify the exact IP like `192.168.0.23`

For more info, look at [Wildfly docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Interfaces+and+ports)